# Problema com PHP em Script verificando Session

Tags: php, html, session, script

Eu tenho que um form mas está escondido apenas quando se clica num botão situado na nav é chamado essa função:

```html
<script>
 function verifLog(){
 <?php 
 session_start(); 
 if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){
   echo "<script> 
   document.location.href ='logOn.php';
  </script>";
  } else {
   echo "<script> 
   document.getElementById('enter').style.display='block';
  </script>";
  }
 ?>
 }
 </script>
```

Mas isto não está a funcionar. 
Alguém sabe o erro que aqui se dá?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim funciona legal, dica, tente manter o seu javascript em um arquivo separado do php.

```html
<?php
session_start();
function verifLog() {
   if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
      header('Location: logOn.php');
   } else {
      ?>
      <script>
         document.getElementById('enter').style.display = 'block';
      </script>
      <?php

   }
}
```